# Объединение запросов

Tags: mysql

Есть два запроса в базу данных, 1-й:

```
SELECT 
@rest_id:=`rest_id`, @user_id:=`user_id_1`, @company_id:=`company_id` 
FROM `schedule` 
WHERE `id` = '$schedule_id'
```

2-й:

```
INSERT INTO `sale` 
  (date_now, schedule_id, rest_id, menu_id, user_id, company_id) 
VALUES (NOW(), '$schedule_id', @rest_id, '$menu_id', @user_id, @company_id)
```

Подскажите, как их объединить в один?

Comment: select + insert в один запрос - можно, конечно, но лучше не надо...

Comment: @DNS А почему `не надо`? INSERT .. SELECT как раз самое адекватное решение.

Comment: @Akina insert-select нормально,  select-insert  странно

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO sale
    (date_now, schedule_id, rest_id, menu_id, user_id, company_id) 
SELECT 
    NOW(), '$schedule_id', rest_id, '$menu_id', user_id_1, company_id
FROM 
    schedule
WHERE 
    id = '$schedule_id'
```

Comment: Боже, Вы батя.
Я был близок)))
Спасибо огромное, очень помогли!!